# Intersection of Hamming Balls

Tags: convex-geometry

I am interested in the volume of the intersection of two Hamming balls of radius say m/6 in m-dimensional space, the distance between whose centers is about \sqrt{m}. I would ideally like this to be a constant or 1/poly(m) fraction of the volume of the Ball itself and wondering if this is true.

This should be an elementary question and I imagine the answer must be well-known, but I am not able to find this on the interweb. Thanks!

Comment: Is this hwk? There are $n\choose i$ points at distance $i$ from the origin.  When $i\approx m/6$, there are about 5 times as many points at distance $i$ as there are at distance $i-1$.  So almost all points in the Hamming ball of radius $m/6$ around the origin are at distance $m/6 \pm \Theta(\log m)$ from the origin.  Similarly, almost all points in the Hamming ball of radius $m/6$ around, say, a given point $p$ with $\sqrt m$ ones and $m-\sqrt m$ zeros, are at distance $m/6 \pm \Theta(\log m)$ from $p$.  But no point has distance $m/6 \pm \Theta(\log m)$ from both the origin and $p$. Right?

Comment: @Neal: don't lots of points have distance $m/6$ both from the origin and $p$?

Comment: Hi @PeterShor!  Yes, you are right.  I should not say "no point".  But very few.  Any point $q$ at distance $m/6$ from the origin has $m/6$ ones.  To also have Hamming distance $m/6$ from $p$, in the $\sqrt m$ coordinates in which $p$ is 1, $q$ has to have exactly $\sqrt m/2$ 1's and $\sqrt m/2$ 0's...  Right?  This is still not a complete argument, but I think it gives the right intuition.

Comment: @Neal: Right. You expect $\sqrt{m}/6$ 1's in those $p$ coordinates. The probability of getting $\sqrt{m}/2$ will be something like $2^{-c \sqrt{m}}$.

Comment: Yes, just what I was going to say.

Comment: I feel like this question might be a better fit for math.SE. If you want then I can migrate it for you (please don't cross-post, ping me in the comments or flag the question).